# Home page for community users

Tags: visualforce, community, partner-communities

I have created a Vf page now i need to add the Vf page to the community user home page when I log into as community user i am getting a message that : https://partner360-developer-edition.na15.force.com/Customer/ is under construction. how can i change the url to my VF page. Please guide me how to get it solved.

Comment: I think you might have added the VF as a iframe component in the home page layout. The URL (src attribute of the iframe) of the VF should be something like this `/communityName/PageName` instead of `/apex/pageName`

Comment: i have done it but it is not working.

Comment: @AnuRaj whats your page name and also your community name?

Comment: page name is dashboard and the community name is Partner Community.

Comment: So your page should be  https://partner360-developer-edition.na15.force.com/PartnerCommunity/dashboard

Comment: again i am assuming your community name is PartnerCommunity.Not sure why you have Customer in URL then?

Answer (score 5):

There's a special one-to-one relationship between a Community and a Force.com Site. It's actually the associated Site entry that holds the Home Page and enabled Visualforce Pages.

The **public** home page needs to be accessible by **"[Your Community Name] Guest"**:

1. go to Setup > Develop > Sites
2. click "[Your Community Name] Guest"
3. hit the Edit button,
4. in 'Active Site Home Page' choose your Visualforce home page,

The **logged in** home page needs to be accessible by **"[Your Community Name] Partner User"**:

1. create a Visualforce Page,
2. go to Setup > Develop > Pages and click Security next to your page
3. move the relevant Login User profile into the Enabled Profiles

Then when you direct visitors to your login page, you must include the `?startURL=/apex/PageName` URL parameter.

Comment: i am not able to understand why we need to create a new Vf page as we are selecting "the Active Site Home Page' choose your Visualforce home page." how the new VF page and the Active Site Home Page are connected to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Go to community edit and click on login pages there you have an option to add site.com or vf pages.

Hope this helps

Comment: Could you possibly expand upon this answer to make it clearer to future readers what the solution entails?

Comment: Please be more specific as your answer is very generic