# Always show a VisualForce page when a user logs in to a community

Tags: visualforce, community

I'm trying to make a VF page to always show when a user logs in to a community.

I've seen [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/23543/12408) and followed it and it works good until a user logs in from the link that he/she copied earlier or somebody gave them.

So the normal flow is:

1. The user logs in
2. The user sees my VF page that is set as *Active Site Home Page*

And what happens when a user logs in from the link:

1. The user copies/gets the link(for example https://mysupermegaawesomecommunity.cs18.force.com/test/00Q11000006ps2t)
2. The user goes to this link
3. The user logs in
4. The user sees that record

What I want to achieve is that the step **4** is replaced by my *Active Site Home Page*

Is there a way to force to show that VF page no matter how a user logs in to a community?

P.S. I know that I can use the *startURL* parameter, but it would have to be present in every single page and the user should not be able to remove it from the link, so that's not really a solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to override the standard Salesforce behavior (= directing the user to the page he requested) you will have to go custom and create your own login page.

You will find more information on customizing login pages here: 
[Customize Login, Logout, and Self-Registration Pages in Your Community](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_customize_login.htm&language=en_US)